# Why is the feature direction chosen in the direction associated with largest eigenvalue of $Σ_T$ in case of more than two classes?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, feature-extraction

Why is the feature direction chosen in the direction associated with largest eigenvalue of $Σ_T$  in case of more than two classes? Please see the following.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think it makes sense, but I don't think it is a universal rule even for two classes. Imagine your two classes are point-clouds in 3d, and they look like parallel pancakes separated by a small gap in the direction perpendicular to pancake plane. I don't think the eigenvector corresponding to largest eigenvalue will be along this vector